# How to use Babylonjs in Reactjs Application?

Tags: reactjs, babylonjs

I have tried import babylonjs in react but its is not working. Does any body know how to import and use the babylonjs in reactjs application.

Thanks.

Comment: i think babylon works with the real DOM. unlike react which is virtual DOM

Comment: Hi, I have installed npm babylonjs it got worked. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have found the answer on your own, however there are several ways now as babylon has matured.  There is actually a Node package for using babylon.js with react here:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-babylonjs

Also there is an install guide for React in Babylon.js in the docs:
https://doc.babylonjs.com/resources/babylonjs_and_reactjs

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Babylon JS is available as **npm** package.  You can easily build a simple `React` Component around a `canvas` and Babylon JS

I have created a minimal example with React+ Babylon:

```
/* Babylon JS is available as **npm** package.  
You can easily build a simple `React` Component around a `canvas` and Babylon JS
I have created a minimal example with React+ Babylon:
 */
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as BABYLON from "babylonjs";

var scene;
var boxMesh;
/**
 * Example temnplate of using Babylon JS with React
 */
class BabylonScene extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { useWireFrame: false, shouldAnimate: false };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // start ENGINE
    this.engine = new BABYLON.Engine(this.canvas, true);

    //Create Scene
    scene = new BABYLON.Scene(this.engine);

    //--Light---
    this.addLight();

    //--Camera---
    this.addCamera();

    //--Meshes---
    this.addModels();

    //--Ground---
    this.addGround();

    // Add Events
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize, false);

    // Render Loop
    this.engine.runRenderLoop(() => {
      scene.render();
    });

    //Animation
    scene.registerBeforeRender(() => {
      boxMesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
      boxMesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    });
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize, false);
  }

  onWindowResize = event => {
    this.engine.resize();
  };

  /**
   * Add Lights
   */
  addLight = () => {
    //---------- LIGHT---------------------
    // Create a basic light, aiming 0,1,0 - meaning, to the sky.
    var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight(
      "light1",
      new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 10, 0),
      scene
    );
  };

  /**
   * Add Camera
   */
  addCamera = () => {
    // ---------------ArcRotateCamera or Orbit Control----------
    var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera(
      "Camera",
      Math.PI / 2,
      Math.PI / 4,
      4,
      BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(),
      scene
    );
    camera.inertia = 0;
    camera.angularSensibilityX = 250;
    camera.angularSensibilityY = 250;

    // This attaches the camera to the canvas
    camera.attachControl(this.canvas, true);
    camera.setPosition(new BABYLON.Vector3(5, 5, 5));
  };

  /**
   * Create Stage and Skybox
   */
  addGround = () => {
    // Create a built-in "ground" shape.
    var ground = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateGround(
      "ground1",
      { height: 6, width: 6, subdivisions: 2 },
      scene
    );
    var groundMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("grass0", scene);
    groundMaterial.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture(
      "./assets/ground.jpeg",
      scene
    );
    ground.material = groundMaterial;

    //Add SkyBox
    var photoSphere = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("skyBox", 16.0, 50.0, scene);
    var skyboxMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("smat", scene);
    skyboxMaterial.emissiveTexture = new BABYLON.Texture(
      "assets/skybox.jpeg",
      scene,
      1,
      0
    );
    skyboxMaterial.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 0);
    skyboxMaterial.specularColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 0);
    skyboxMaterial.emissiveTexture.uOffset = -Math.PI / 2; // left-right
    skyboxMaterial.emissiveTexture.uOffset = 0.1; // up-down
    skyboxMaterial.backFaceCulling = false;
    photoSphere.material = skyboxMaterial;
  };

  /**
   * Add Models
   */
  addModels = () => {
    // Add BOX
    boxMesh = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateBox(
      "box",
      { height: 1, width: 1, depth: 1 },
      scene
    );
    boxMesh.position.y = 1;

    var woodMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("wood", scene);
    woodMaterial.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture(
      "./assets/portal_cube.png",
      scene
    );
    boxMesh.material = woodMaterial;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <canvas
        style={{ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight }}
        ref={canvas => {
          this.canvas = canvas;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default BabylonScene;
```

Live Demo:

**https://codesandbox.io/s/babylonjs-react-template-w2i1k**

[image]